# How to add start_url as an item?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to Python and Scrapy. I want `item['Source_Website']` to be the url I am crawling. How can I achieve this?

I tried `item['Source_Website'] = selector.ulr` and `item['Source_Website'] = start_urls` but no luck.

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from shikari.items import ShikariItem

class Radiate (BaseSpider) :
  name = "sss"
  download_delay = 3
  concurrent_requests = 1
  allowed_domains = ["website.com"]
  start_urls = ['http://www.website.com/1',
                'http://www.website.com/2']

  def parse(self, response) :
    sel = Selector (response)
    item = ShikariItem ()
    item['Heading'] = str (sel.xpath ('//h1/text()').extract ())
    item['Source_Website'] = 
    return item
```

Comment: you can also avoid using another selector,  as the response works as one too. just juse `response.xpath` as you were doing, no need to create another one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `response.url` as follows:

```
item['Source_Website'] = response.url
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. I will accept answer once it allows me.